# NativeScript RadListView Staggered with Web Image Cache

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to use RadListView with a staggered layout to load images using Web Image Cache. My problem is that percentage heights (100%) doesn't work on Android. Works just fine on iOS but on Android it will only show if I set a fixed value for the height, which I don't want.

```
<GridLayout tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
        <RadListView [items]="products"> 
                <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                      <WebImage placeholder="~/images/placeholder.png" [src]="item.picture" stretch="fill"></WebImage>
                </ng-template>
                <ListViewStaggeredLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" spanCount="2"></ListViewStaggeredLayout>
        </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try the default `Image` component, did that work? As you have set the stretch mode to fill, it should take care of width / height of the image based on available space. I'm not quite sure why you need % at all here.

Comment: I need to cache the image so I do not want to use the normal Image component else it acts weird with a lot of images.

Comment: Absolutely understood, but I was just trying to understand whether it's a issue with web image plugin if Image component works as expected for you at least in terms of layout / sizing.

Comment: I have the opposite problem with the normal Image component. Android works fine but iOS won't work without a defined height (which from what I've read is a more common issue).

Comment: https://github.com/VideoSpike/nativescript-web-image-cache/issues/50 here is the same problem I am having, but his solution only applies to a single image. I don't know how I would dynamically size for many items.